# How to format an already formatted number to another number format?

Tags: wordpress, number-formatting

I have already number formatted value. It is formatted as:

```
$val = number_format($val,'2', '.', ',');
$val = hook_price_filter($val);
```

It is a Wordpress core theme code. It provides a price hook.

So, I want to format it to another number format as `number_format($val,'2', ',', '.')` e.g. from 2,152.14 to 2.152,14

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the commas, because `number_format` wants a float number as first parameter, not a string:

```
number_format( str_replace(',', '', $val), 2, ',', '.' );
```